# Flask werkzeug\formparser.py exception

Tags: python, flask

Trying to run a simple flask app in PyDev and it's giving me this error:

```
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\formparser.py", line 28
from werkzeug.wsgi import make_line_iter, \ get_input_stream, get_content_length
                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Does anybody know what this is? Does Flask even work anymore?

Comment: Thanks, I get this now SyntaxError: trailing comma not allowed without surrounding parentheses It looks like PyDev is messing with this thing Any idea how to stop it, I cant seem to find it...

Comment: Which version of `werkzeug` are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding '\' to a line tells python that you are going to continue this line in the next line. E.g.

```
1 + 2 + \
3
```

is read by python as

```
1 + 2 + 3
```

because of this, '\' always needs to be the last character in a line of code. Your error can be easily reproduced by doing anything like

```
print('hello') \ print('world')
```

which will raise

```
  File "C:/Users/.../test.py", line 1
      print('hello') \ print('world')
                              ^
  SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

so, just either remove the backslash or write anything after it into a new line.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I got it working, it looks like this is a problem with Python 3.6? I switched to 3.7 and it works. Cheers and Happy Holidays!

Comment: Gladly! Happy Holidays to you as well ;-)