# Python error: unexpected character after line continuation character. What do I do?

Tags: python, syntax-error

```html
pe = 0
n = 0
po = 0
x = 1
while x!=0:
    y = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if y<0:
        n = n+y
    elif y%2==0 and y>0:
        pe = pe+y
    else:
        po = po+y
    x = y
print("The sum of negative numbers is", n \n "The sum of positive even numbers is", pe \n "The sum of positive odd numbers is", po)
```

I get the error mentioned in the title when I run this program. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The backslash isn't inside a string literal, so it indicates a line continuation - the rest of that line is invalid syntax. Try something like `print("... is", n, "\nThe ...", ...)`.

Comment: look at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817694/flask-werkzeug-formparser-py-exception/53818077#53818077) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line continuation character is the backslash `\` and it is used to split long lines of python code (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python) or this section of [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id19)).

In your case, the last line:

```
print("The sum of negative numbers is", n \n "The sum of positive even numbers is", pe \n "The sum of positive odd numbers is", po)
```

should have the `\n` chars inside the string literals (or some other solution, but you cannot leave them like that inside the `print()` function):

```
print("The sum of negative numbers is", n, "\nThe sum of positive even numbers is", pe, "\nThe sum of positive odd numbers is", po)
```